# How to apply custom/override CSS on Vuetify component?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-material

Suppose I have added the `v-text-field` component of Vuetify in my Vue component like

```
<v-text-field v-model="email"name="email" type="email" color="#90C143" label="Email">
```

When I inspect that element, it generates normal HTML like

```
<div class="v-input v-input--has-state theme--light v-text-field v-text-field--is-booted" style="">
      <div class="v-input__control">
        <div class="v-input__slot">
          <div class="v-text-field__slot">
            <label for="input-39" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; right: auto; position: absolute;">Email
            </label>
            <input name="email" id="input-39" type="email">
          </div>
          <div class="v-input__append-inner">
            <div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--">
              <i role="button" class="v-icon notranslate v-icon--link material-icons theme--light" style="">                    
              </i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I have to process, If I want to customize the Whole CSS for that `v-text-field` without affecting the functionality

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a css class inside the component:

```
<style scoped>
.text-field{
    color: #90C143 !important; /* this will override the existing property applied */
    /* add whatever properties you want */
}
</style>
```

Then  in the component add this to class instead of color property:

```
<v-text-field v-model="email"name="email" type="email" class="text-field" label="Email">
```

You can use only the predefined classes given in [vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors).

If you want to use custom color on the color property you can set your
own theme in Vuetify object in main.js:

```
Vue.use(Vuetify)

const vuetify = new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: '#90C143',
        secondary: '#b0bec5',
        anchor: '#8c9eff',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Now you can use the specified theme overrides in any component:

```
<v-text-field v-model="email"name="email" type="email" color="primary" label="Email">
```

You can alternatively apply CSS globally in `app.vue`:

```
<style>
/* don't use scoped css */

.theme--light.v-text-field>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot:before {
    border-color: #90C143;
}

.theme--light.v-label {
    color: #90C143;
}

.theme--light.v-input:not(.v-input--is-disabled) input, .theme--light.v-input:not(.v-input--is-disabled) textarea {
    color: #90C143;
}
</style>
```

Comment: okay, but what to do if I want to customize all the CSS for the particular vuetify component and don't want to use !important CSS property.

Comment: Just check the css class in the developer console and override the  class with your own style in app.vue

Comment: Okay got it, Thank You so much

Comment: If you have any links where i can design mobile views as well as desktop views with vuetify material design, please share...

Comment: Read about grid layouts in vuetify, that is more than enough to make your views mobile responsive